# Table not updating

Tags: php, html, mysql

Struggling to update a row I know I am posts the right value by throwing up a `var_dump()` agains the $`_POST` but it must be the method I am using to update the table:

```
<?php

/******************************************************************
**  ACTION SCRIPT TO UPDATE THE CATEGORY AFTER CHANGES ARE MADE  **
******************************************************************/ 

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
include_once'../../config.php';

try {

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);

    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "UPDATE cat_list SET cat_title = :cat_title, cat_color = :cat_color, cat_icon = :cat_icon WHERE cat_id = :cat_id";
    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute(array(":cat_title"=>$_POST["cat_title"], 
                          ":cat_color"=> $_POST["cat_color"]), 
                          ":cat_icon"=> $_POST["cat_icon"]), 
                          ":cat_id"=> $_POST["cat_id"]));



if ($query) {
    header ('Location: ../list_cat.php?success=2');
}
else{
}
    $dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

}
?>
```

Here is the form:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<?php 

require_once '../../db_con.php'; 

if(!empty($_GET['cat_id'])){
    $cat = intval($_GET['cat_id']);
try{
    $results = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM cat_list WHERE cat_id = ?');
    $results->bindParam(1, $cat);
    $results->execute();

    } catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
    }

    $cat = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
    if($cat == FALSE){

        echo '<div class="container">';
        echo "<img src='../img/404.jpg' style='margin: 40px auto; display: block;' />";
        echo "<h1 style='margin: 40px auto; display: block; text-align: center;' />Oh Crumbs! You upset the bubba!</h1>";
        echo '<a href="userList.php"  style="margin: 40px auto; display: block; text-align: center;">Get me outta here!</a>';
        echo'</div>';
        die();
    }
}

?>

    <form action="actions/update_cat.php" method="POST" id="rtf" name="">

        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $cat['cat_id'] ?>" name="cat_id" />
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $cat['cat_title'] ?>" name="cat_title" /><br><br>



        <div class="catOptionsMenu">

    <!-- COLOUR PICKER FOR CATEGORY HEADERS -->

            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="cat_color" value="#d31b26">
            <label for="radio1"><div class="redSelect" onclick="button_click('#d31b26');"></div></label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="cat_color" value="#f9c04c">
            <label for="radio2"><div class="yellowSelect" onclick="button_click('#f9c04c');" ></div></label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="cat_color" value="#ec9292">
            <label for="radio3"><div class="pinkSelect" onclick="button_click('#ec9292');"></div></label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="cat_color" value="#b7d04e">
            <label for="radio4"><div class="greenSelect" onclick="button_click('#b7d04e');"></div></label> 

            <input type="radio" id="radio5" name="cat_color" value="#637a91">
            <label for="radio5"><div class="slateSelect" onclick="button_click('#637a91');"></div></label> 

            <input type="radio" id="radio6" name="cat_color" value="#AEA8D3">
            <label for="radio6"><div class="purpleSelect" onclick="button_click('#AEA8D3');"></div></label> 

            <input type="radio" id="radio13" name="cat_color" value="#72bce9">
            <label for="radio13"><div class="blueSelect" onclick="button_click('#72bce9');"></div></label>      

        <br><br>


            <!-- ICON PICKER FOR CATEGORY HEADERS -->

            <input type="radio" id="radio7" type="radio" name="cat_icon" value='<i class="fa fa-phone" style="font-size: 2em;"></i>'>
            <label for="radio7"><div class="iconSelect" onclick="button_click_icon1()"><i class='fa fa-phone' style='font-size: 2em;'></i></div></label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio8" type="radio" name="cat_icon" value='<i class="fa fa-graduation-cap" style="font-size: 2em;"></i>'>
            <label for="radio8"><div class="iconSelect" onclick="button_click_icon2()"><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap' style='font-size: 2em;'></i></div></label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio9" type="radio" name="cat_icon" value='<i class="fa fa-users" style="font-size: 2em;"></i>'>
            <label for="radio9"><div class="iconSelect" onclick="button_click_icon3()"><i class='fa fa-users' style='font-size: 2em;'></i></div></label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio10" type="radio" name="cat_icon" value='<i class="fa fa-question-circle" style="font-size: 2em;"></i>'>
            <label for="radio10"><div class="iconSelect" onclick="button_click_icon4()"><i class='fa fa-question-circle' style='font-size: 2em;'></i></div></label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio11" type="radio" name="cat_icon" value='<i class="fa fa-file-text" style="font-size: 2em;"></i>'>
            <label for="radio11"><div class="iconSelect" onclick="button_click_icon5()"><i class='fa fa-file-text' style='font-size: 2em;'></i></div></label>

            <input type="radio" id="radio12" type="radio" name="cat_icon" value='<i class="fa fa-at" style="font-size: 2em;"></i>'>
            <label for="radio12"><div class="iconSelect" onclick="button_click_icon6()"><i class='fa fa-at' style='font-size: 2em;'></i></div></label>



        </div>
        <br><br><br>

        <!-- CATEGORY HEADER DEMO BUILD VIEW -->

        <div class="indexBox">
            <div style="<?php echo 'background-color: '.$cat["cat_color"].'' ?>" class="indexBoxHeader" id="box">
                <siv id="icon"><?php echo ''.$cat["cat_icon"].'' ?></div>
            <div class="indexBoxFooter">
                <div class='printchatbox' id='printchatbox'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br> 


        <input onclick="formsubmit()" type="submit" value="Update Category" name="submit"/>


    </form>
```

I believe it is the UPDATE query in the action script - I know it isn't as secure as it could be but I will tidy that up.

Comment: Check if $query->execute return false. If so, check $pdo->errorInfo array (simply var_dump them for debug)

Comment: the trouble is the page just display blank on the action script

Comment: put your code from $dbh = new pdo( ...) to $dbh->prepare() statement inside try/catch block and have your catch block something like this to get exact error message: catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception -> ';
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set argument for `execute` properly. It's an array, and now you have something weird:

```
$query->execute(array(":cat_title"=>$_POST["cat_title"], 
    ":cat_color"=> $_POST["cat_color"]),  // extra )
     ":cat_icon"=> $_POST["cat_icon"]),   // extra )
     ":cat_id"=> $_POST["cat_id"]));
```

Should be:

```
$query->execute(array(
    ":cat_title"=>$_POST["cat_title"], 
    ":cat_color"=> $_POST["cat_color"],
    ":cat_icon"=> $_POST["cat_icon"],
    ":cat_id"=> $_POST["cat_id"]
));
```

Comment: Nice :) I've missed that...Too much code for one day...